# How do I change iTerm2 to use rsync instead of the default scp for downloading?

Tags: shell, ssh, rsync, scp, iterm2

## Question:

How do I change iTerm2's default downloading protocol, `scp`, to use `rsync` instead?

I want to use the iTerm2's CMD+Click feature to download a file from a server that I am ssh'd into without having to write a lengthy command, example of a length command:

`rsync -avP username@hostname.com:/path/to/file.txt ~/Downloads`

## Reason:

I'm working in a server that prohibits scp, due to security reasons.

Currently, iTerm2 allows the user to CMD+Click a file on a server they are ssh'd into, and it will download the file to use the users `$HOME/Downloads` directory (on OSX). But this fails for me due to the restriction on scp.

Open to other ideas. I can, of course, simply use rsync to download it via commandline as stated above, but typing that a lot is cumbersome.

I tried using ChatGPT to give me a the answer, but they suggested to go to the preferences, profile, and point me to a setting that did not exist.

The iTerm2 FAQ https://iterm2.com/faq.html mentions that iTerm2 uses scp.
I read the iTerm2 scp troubleshooting guide: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/wikis/scp-not-connecting
But it's not due to a connection problem.